# IOS : Turn on/off caps lock led through software

Tags: iphone, ios, keyboard, led, capslock

Is it possible to turn the led off/on of a bluetooth key board within the code ?

(it seems not possible, but I'd rather ask to be sure, may by someone found a workaround)